# How do I limit my sql to an end date in my Access report?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I created an Access database to track work orders and create/print schedules.
On the report I have two different print buttons. One prints the weeks schedule I'm currently viewing to my printer and the other button prints the current week and all future weeks to a PDF. My code for the 2nd button changes the SQL data source and works perfect.

That code looks like this (see pic):
[Working SQL code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dej02.png)

-----Set default printer to PDF-----

```
-working code-
```

-----Set the datasource to show everything from this week and future weeks excluding unscheduled (NULL)-----

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim vbDblQuote As String

'set variable to = "
vbDblQuote = Chr(34)

'SQL for the data source
strSQL = "SELECT tblSchedule.ScheduleID, tblSchedule.Scheduled, tblSchedule.Attending, "
strSQL = strSQL & "tblSchedule.Time, tblSchedule.Account, tblSchedule.Address , "
strSQL = strSQL & "tblSchedule.Comments, tblSchedule.Contact, tblSchedule.WONumber "
strSQL = strSQL & "FROM tblSchedule "
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE (((DatePart(" & vbDblQuote & "ww" & vbDblQuote & ",[Scheduled])) "
strSQL = strSQL & ">=DatePart(" & vbDblQuote & "ww" & vbDblQuote & ",Date()))"
strSQL = strSQL & "AND ((Year([Scheduled]))>=Year(Date())))"
strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY tblSchedule.Scheduled, tblSchedule.Attending, tblSchedule.Time;"

'set data source for the report
Reports![rptSchedule].Report.RecordSource = strSQL
```

-----Print and restore default printer-----

```
-working code-
```

Now I want to enable the user to select an **end date** for the report. I changed the code every which way I could but can't get it to work now. Can anyone help me with the new SQL? It contains a variable to accept the users date.

The new code looks like this (see pic): [New Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlQ0D.png)

-----Set default printer to PDF-----

```
-working code-
```

-----Get the end date from user-----

```
Dim endDate
endDate = InputBox("Select an End Date m/d/yy")
```

-----Set the datasource to show everything from this week and future weeks excluding unscheduled (NULL)-----

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim vbDblQuote As String

'set variable to = "
vbDblQuote = Chr(34)

Dim mySQLVariable

'set variable to user’s end date
mySQLVariable = endDate

'SQL for the data source
strSQL = "SELECT tblSchedule.ScheduleID, tblSchedule.Scheduled, tblSchedule.Attending, "
strSQL = strSQL & "tblSchedule.Time, tblSchedule.Account, tblSchedule.Address , "
strSQL = strSQL & "tblSchedule.Comments, tblSchedule.Contact, tblSchedule.WONumber "
strSQL = strSQL & "FROM tblSchedule "
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE (((DatePart(" & vbDblQuote & "ww" & vbDblQuote & ",[Scheduled])) "
strSQL = strSQL & ">=DatePart(" & vbDblQuote & "ww" & vbDblQuote & ",Date()))"
strSQL = strSQL & "AND ((Year([Scheduled]))>=Year(Date())))"

strSQL = strSQL & "OR (((DatePart(" & vbDblQuote & "ww" & vbDblQuote & ", [Scheduled])) "
strSQL = strSQL & "<= DatePart(" & vbDblQuote & "ww" & vbDblQuote & ", Date() + '" & (mySQLVariable) & "')) "
strSQL = strSQL & "And ((Year([Scheduled])) = Year(Date() + '" & (mySQLVariable) & "'))) "

strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY tblSchedule.Scheduled, tblSchedule.Attending, tblSchedule.Time;"

'set data source for the report
Reports![Reset_Schedule].Report.RecordSource = strSQL
```

-----Print and restore default printer-----

```
-working code-
```

I hope this is clear enough to understand my problem.

Comment: `Year(Date() + '" & (mySQLVariable)`  Should this just be `year(mySqlVariable)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the help Nathan_Sav. I tried your suggestion but still couldn't get it to work. I thought you were on to something there. I even tried changing the variable type to string, integer, date and even variant. I really think the problem is in the SQL somewhere. Please, any Access/SQL experts out there that can help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Advise to use a form control instead of InputBox for input of parameter. Validating InputBox input is difficult. Why code to set RecordSource of report? Set it in design and use WHERE argument of DoCmd.OpenReport to apply filter criteria.

Comment: Cross post https://www.utteraccess.com/topics/2061769